# How to send order confirmation email in magento 2 programmatically?

Tags: magento2, email

`Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email -> Order -> Disabled`

Where should I look and which module or modal to send the same email programmatically?

**Update**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);

$emailSender = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender');
$emailSender->send($order);
```

If I `Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email -> Order -> Disabled` the above code doesn't trigger the email. Or if I enable, it send
2 email. I don't want the email that magento trigger for order confirmation. I want to do it.

Comment: Hello @iamkdev, it will send admin too?

Answer (score 7):

Look at `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender`. This is where you'll find the method to send the order confirmation for a given order.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without influencing Magento Core functionality (which happens when using a plugin) would be to inject a custom `OrderIdentity` that will always return true for `isEnabled`.

I tried out the solution on Magento OSS ver. 2.4.2-p1.

First, you extend `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity` and just return true for `isEnabled`. Alhtough, extending should be kept to a minimum, I think it is ok in this case, as we won't override the original class with a preference. We will just use it as a argument in di.xml.

**app/code/Vendor/YourModule/Model/Order/Email/Container/EnabledOrderIdentity.php:**

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\YourModule\Model\Order\Email\Container;

/**
 * An order identity that will ignore the configuration for sales_email/order/enabled.
 */
class EnabledOrderIdentity extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity
{
    /**
     * Always return true and do not consider config options
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isEnabled(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, as we have our custom identity that won't care when `sales_email/order/enabled` is disabled, we can create a virtual type that replaces the `identityContainer` argument for `OrderSender` with our custom one.
This virtual type can be used as argument for places where the injected OrderSender should be able to send emails without paying attention to the sales_email/order/enabled` setting.

**app/code/Vendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml:**

```php
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Virtual OrderSender type that ignores order email disable setting -->
    <virtualType name="Vendor\YourModule\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender"
                 type="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="identityContainer" xsi:type="object">Vendor\YourModule\Model\Order\Email\Container\EnabledOrderIdentity</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <!-- Example usage -->
    <type name="Class\Where\You\Want\Custom\OrderSender\Test">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="orderSender" xsi:type="object">Vendor\YourModule\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

In the class where you want to programmatically send the email while `sales_email/order/enabled` is set to disabled, must use constructor injection (instead of ObjectManager) to inject your custom OrderSender.

**This can look like the following example:**

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Class\Where\You\Want\Custom\OrderSender;

use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;

class Test {
    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository;
    
    /**
     * @var OrderSender
     */
    private OrderSender $orderSender;

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param OrderSender $orderSender
     */
    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        OrderSender $orderSender
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
    }

    public function someFunction() {
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get(8); // Your logic to get the order
        $this->orderSender->send($order); // Order sender has custom identity that ignores settings
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Simply you can use below code to send order email

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(true);
$order->save();
$session = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
$session->setForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess(true);
$emailSender = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender');
$emailSender->send($order);
```

**You should not use the ObjectManager directly!**

Answer (score 0):

A hacky script to force send order confirmation emails, used to recover when some SMTP connection errors occurred.

Don't use object manager or bootstrap magento like this in production code.

```php
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get(Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$obj->get(\Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation::class)->startEnvironmentEmulation(1, 'frontend'); # replace with store id

$incrementIds = [
    '123456789',
];

$counter = 1;
foreach ($incrementIds as $incrementId) {
    echo str_pad((string)$counter, 3, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . " - $incrementId - " ;
    $order = $obj->create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::class);
    $order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
    if (!$order->getId()) {
        echo "DOES NOT EXIST" . PHP_EOL;
        continue;
    }

    $orderSender = $obj->create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender::class);
    $orderSender->send($order);
    $counter++;
    echo "SENT" . PHP_EOL;
}

echo "DONE" . PHP_EOL;
```